# How to install Realtek RTL8723BE wireless driver on debian?

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, kernel-modules, realtek

I installed Debian Wheezy 7.8 on a Lenovo G50-70 x64, it seems that I don't have the driver for my wireless card installed, the output of `iwconfig`:

> lo        no wireless extensions.
>
> eth0      no wireless extensions.

Here's the output of `lspci -nn`:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b723]
```

As you can see my ethernet controller has the driver installed and it's working fine, but the Network Controller which is my wifi card is not installed.

I tried looking in the [device database of debian](https://wiki.debian.org/DeviceDatabase/PCI) for the vendor and device id `10ec:b723` to find which module I need to install but I couldn't find it, although I found my ethernet controller and which module it requires, does this mean that this card is not supported ?

While searching I found the firmware of **RTL8723BE** in the packge `firmware-realtek` for Jessie so I installed it from [wheezy backports](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/firmware-realtek), but I don't know if this is the driver or not, and nothing has changed.

I also found this repository on github [rtlwifi_new](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new) and tried installing the driver from source, but I got these errors when I ran `make`:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/build M=/home/peter/rtlwifi_new modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64'
  CC [M]  /home/peter/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu/hw.o
/home/peter/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu/hw.c: In function ‘rtl92cu_update_hal_rate_mask’:
/home/peter/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu/hw.c:2094:25: error: ‘struct ieee80211_sta’ has no member named ‘bandwidth’
/home/peter/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu/hw.c:2094:40: error: ‘IEEE80211_STA_RX_BW_40’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/peter/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu/hw.c:2094:40: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[5]: *** [/home/peter/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu/hw.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [/home/peter/rtlwifi_new/rtl8192cu] Error 2
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/peter/rtlwifi_new] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So what should do in this case, where can I find the module I need for this card ? and If this Github repository is what I need, how can I fix these errors ? I already have `build-essential` and the linux headers installed.

**Update**

After searching for a while I found that the `rtl8723be.ko` module is available in the the kernel version `3.16` of the testing release Jessie, is it safe to update my kernel using the [Wheezy backport](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64) ?

**Update 2**

When I run `modprobe rtl8723be` I get the following:

```
FATAL: Module rtl8723be not found.
```

Comment: just a thought, after your install of firmware-realtek what says sudo modprobe rtl8723be ?

Comment: @taliezin it says `FATAL: Module rtl8723be not found.`

Comment: than what is installed? apt show? And for the second part did you do: sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r`, because I successfully build it but for 3.10 kernel, but as istated kernel shuld be > 3.0?

Comment: @taliezin my kernel version is `3.2.0-4-amd64`.

Comment: I understood that: /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64 thats why I am asking if everything for building modules is installed.

Comment: @taliezin what other packages should I install to be able to build this module ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21911/discussion-between-taliezin-and-peter).

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed readme starting info i.e. in this repo

> This code will build on any kernel 4.2 and newer

this is kernel code compatible with 4.2 and higher.
So suggestion for you will be

1. update kernel to 4.2 or newer either by debian repo i.e. using aptitude
2. revert to earlier commit and try compiling. easier way to test will be quickly switch to test branch and compile as test branch is valid for 3.0 and newer.

let me know if you need exact commit id.